# Can't configure thin to start at system boot on CentOs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, thin

I can't configure thin to start at system boot, I am new to Linux

I have CentOS 5.7

Thin gem was installed and thin was installed too.

```
sudo gem install thin
sudo thin install
```

and when I try to configure thin to start at system boot I get an error

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig --level 345 thin on
error reading information on service thin: No such file or directory
```

Anybody have an idea why I get this error?
Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`sudo mv /etc/rc.d/thin /etc/rc.d/init.d/thin`, and retry.

Comment: Thanks, That worked fine, any explanation why did this happen? and why I needed to copy the file?

Comment: After <code>thin install</code>, as the message after installation says, the script 'thin' is installed into <code>/etc/rc.d</code>. And if we want <code>thin</code> to be installed as a service, the script must be put into <code>init.d</code>. Maybe you can read the scripts under <code>init.d</code> for more information. Sorry for my pool English:)